# Где хранятся метаданные файла?

Tags: windows, файлы, метаданные

Мне стало интересно, где хранятся метаданные файлов. Погуглив, я узнал, что в `Windows` они хранятся в отдельных метафайлах и прикрепляются к своим файлам. Но как тогда скачав файл с сайта, в нем хранятся метаданные? Получается метаданные хранятся в самом файле? Или например когда мы загружаем на [сайт](http://exif.regex.info/exif.cgi) файл, то как сайт узнает о метаданных файла?

Comment: О каких конкретно метаданных речь? Если вас интересует exif, то они записаны прямо внутри файла, никакого отдельного метафайла для exif нет.

Comment: @andreymal exif метаданные. Тогда интересно, а где именно в файле они записаны? В конце файла? Где-то в середине? Я полагаю, что зависит от разрешения файла. Я в интернете не смог найти информацию по этому поводу, можете поделится какой-нибудь ссылкой для ознакомления?

Comment: У каждого формата свои собственные правила, где какие данные располагать в файле

Comment: @andreymal я это понимаю, но вот например jpg, где расположены exif метаданные и в каком виде? Где хотя бы можно почитать об этом?

Comment: В спецификациях интересующего формата. В частности, в [спецификации exif](http://www.exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF) про JPEG написано, что exif-данные начинаются с маркера APP1 (байты `FF E1`) и обычно он располагается в самом начале JPEG-файла ([пример](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsPAo.png))

Comment: Также очень подробно на английском Stack Overflow расписали https://stackoverflow.com/a/14115795

Comment: @andreymal спасибо за ссылку на английский Stack Overflow, очень помогло